# Sending SOAP Request to .NET Web Service via libcurl!

Tags: .net, curl, libcurl

I'm Trying to send a SOAP request to a .NET Webservice which accepts an XML string. This is my sample XML string stored in char array:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <BankDeposit xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <xmlParam>
        <onlineTxn xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.tempuri.org/">
        <TXN>
            <TxnID>17032011111230</TxnID>
            <CCID>73467836483</CCID>
            <ACNO>899000777</ACNO>
            <TXAMT>52</TXAMT>
        </TXN>
    </onlineTxn>
    </xmlParam>
    </BankDeposit>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

The code I'm using to submit to .NET webservice as follows:

```
int PostRequest(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    char buffer[2000]=//XML String to be sent.
    int res = -1;
    struct curl_httppost *post=NULL, *last=NULL;
    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    unsigned int buffer_size = 2000;

    fp = fopen("res.xml","w");
    fpreq = fopen ("req.xml", "w");

    curl=curl_easy_init();
    if(curl)
    {
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-type:application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action=\"http://tempuri.org/BankDeposit\"");    
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILE, fp);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data); //For writing the responses recieved 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, buffer_size);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, buffer);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, FALSE);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progress_func);    

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);  
        curl_slist_free_all(headers); 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        printf("CURL Easy Perform Status Code: %d\n", res);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fpreq);
    return res;
}
```

The trouble is: "The contents are not getting posted to the Web Service". I have debugged my .NET service and it doesn't receive any data from the sender.

My Webservice operation is : BankDeposit.

Accepts a parameter named ; xmlParam of TYPE: String

Please help me with this. Need your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two possible problems here:

1. you open two files for **writing** (using fopen). If you open the files using "w" you will clear out the files.
2. there is no code to import the data from the "now formatted" files.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION to get a full trace of what libcurl sends and receives. Make sure the request looks exactly the way you want it.

Your request probably make libcurl use "Expect: 100-continue" which is a header that is often badly handled by servers so try disabling that.